# creating a org.w3c.dom.Document object and appending it to a node

Tags: java, xml

I have a xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Book>
<Author>
XYZ
</Author>
</Book>
```

I want to add a new node suppose Edition into this like:

```
<Book>
<Author>
XYZ
</Author>
<Edition>
5
</Edition>
</Book>
```

How can I do this using java?

I tried doing it as:
In a method I am passing the entire node and new node as a String but its throwing `org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMDOMException` when I did this:

```
Document doc = null;
doc = createEmptyDocument(true);
Element child = doc.createElement(childNodeName);
child.setNodeValue(childNodeValue);
node.appendChild(chid);//node is the main node which has all the elements
```

Comment: you are appending "chid" instead of "child"

Comment: Sir I am appending child, by mistake I wrote it as chid.

Comment: SHow us the exception, including stack trace.

Comment: [Mar 07 15:39:13] [23313]  WARN [Supplier_GDBC_1] (ServerThread.java:573) - Connector for supplier GDBC's message Itinerary Storage or Update returned null rather than throwing an exception (obsolete
behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using something like DOM4J instead of the W3C classes.  It adds a layer on top that makes manipulations easier.